Pronunciation of the verb 'surfe'
The verb surfen as in 'Ich surfe nie.', how should I pronounce this verb?
If it were pure Deutsch word, it would be like 'ZOOR-fuh',
but I heard it pronounced as 'SUHR-fuh' as in the English word surf.
Which one is the correct pronunciation?
If the second one 'SUHR-fuh' is correct, is it because it is an imported word?

The common process of integrating a word into the German language is to leave the pronounciation intact. That is: as intact as German pronounciation allows.
Therefore the lexem "surf-" is pronounced "sörf" (thereabouts). On the other hand a word used in a German sentence becomes a German word and that means inflection is done normally. It is inflected like any other German Verb:

ich surf-e
du surf-st
er/sie/es surf-t
wir surf-en
ihr surf-t
sie surf-en

And the same in Präteritum/Perfekt:

ich surf-t-e
ich habe ge-surf-t

The process of incorporation into the German language continues with adaption of the spelling. Take, for example, the French bureau, which was originally written like this until the beginning of the 20th century, but since then the spelling has changed to "Büro", because this resembles most closely the way it is pronounced. Conceivably "surfen" will be written "sörfen" a 100 years from now (if that is still a thing then).
This is the common way. Notice, that there is indeed motivated abandonment of this common way: e.g. the plural of "Kaktus" is "Kakteen" (not "Kaktusse") and the plural of "Atlas" is "Atlanten". It can be argued that "Atlas" is just a contraction and the "-nt-" has been lost, as one can see in "Atlantis", but on the other hand, "Atlas" is a proper name (of the deity holding the sky up). There is also a still ongoing discussion about "to upload"/"to download": is it "ich habe up-ge-loadet" (like "ein-ge-kauft") in German or "ich habe gedownloadet" (like "ge-lesen")? In other words, are these "separable Verben" or not. If they are separabel it should be "ich loade up" too. Maybe it is me, but this doesn't sound quite right.
Those motivated deviations are plain wrong quite often too: the plural of "Espresso" is not "Espressi" and if you order "due espressi" in an Italian Café you will get (bewildered) stares in return. An espresso is a "quick coffee" and you are to order "due caffé". "Espresso" is the way you drink it, not some sort of coffee.
Same with the people who write "das Konklave": The plural, would this word indeed be neutral, would have to be "die Konklavien" instead of "die Konklaven". Since it is feminine "Konklaven" is correct.

"Take, for example, the French bureaux, which was originally written like this until the beginning of the 20th century" - I suppose bureau?

'The plural, would this word indeed be neutral, would have to be "die Konklavien"' - is this supposed to be analogous to any other neuter words?

"Conceivably "surfen" will be written "sörfen" a 100 years from now" - or maybe "ßörfen"? :)

@O.R.Mapper: the "bureaux" was a typo - I corrected it.

DWDS ( https://www.dwds.de/wb/surfen ) gives a long "ö" in IPA, which strikes me as wrong. It is also not what I hear in their sound file (which is better sound quality than the wikimedia file). I think I say [sœɐ̯fn].
Interestingly, DWDS gives the voiceless "s" as the standard pronunciation, which would be the English original, while standard German would require [z-]. (I couldn't have known because I am a Southern German speaker, they mostly do [s-] anyway).

Wiktionary has the answer. It is:
[ˈsœːɐ̯fə]
If it was a real German word, it would be written as söafe where ö and a build a diphthong. The ö is long and stressed, but turns to an a before the f. The last vowel is a schwa sound.
Wiktionary has the pronunciation for every German word, even for all grammatical forms of all words. You just need to know the IPA = International Phonetic Alphabet. I don't find the English Wikipedia article about IPA very useful, but German Wikipedia has a list of all phonetic symbols with links to sites with further explanations: Liste der IPA-Zeichen
Very often Wiktionary also has audio samples, and this is the case here too.

Go to: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/surfe
There you find this:

surfe (Deutsch)
Konjugierte Form
Nebenformen:
2. Person Singular Imperativ Präsens Aktiv: surf
Worttrennung:
sur·fe
Aussprache:
IPA: [ˈsœːɐ̯fə]
Hörbeispiele:  surfe (Info)
Grammatische Merkmale:
2. Person Singular Imperativ Präsens Aktiv des Verbs surfen
1. Person Singular Indikativ Präsens Aktiv des Verbs surfen
1. Person Singular Konjunktiv I Präsens Aktiv des Verbs surfen
3. Person Singular Konjunktiv I Präsens Aktiv des Verbs surfen

English translation:

surfe (German)
Conjugated form
Secondary forms:
2nd person singular imperative present active: surf
Word separation:
sur·fe
Pronunciation:
IPA: [ˈsœːɐ̯fə]
Audio samples:    surfe (Info)
Grammatical characteristics:
2nd person singular imperative present active of the verb surfen
1st person singular indicative present active of the verb surfen
1st person singular subjunctive I present active of the verb surfen
3rd person singular subjunctive I present active of the verb surfen


Are you sure about the length of the vowel? In a sentence like "Söder surft" I perceive the second ö-vowel as shorter than the first.

@Alazon: »Können Löffel plötzlich surfen?« The ö-sounds from the first three words in this sentence are all short. Die ö-sound in surfen is much longer. It's true, that the ö in the name Söder is also long, maybe even a tiny bit longer, but still the length of the ö-sound in surfen and its grammatical forms is also clearly on the long side.

Per Wiktionary: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/De-surfe.ogg I've noticed that when German borrows verbs, it tends to keep the original pronunciation, allowing changes for sounds that are difficult for German speakers to pronounce. But the German verb inflections are added as if it was a native German word. The endings are then pronounced as in German. The "real" German form is "wellenreiten", see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wellenreiten, but it seems that it exists mainly as a noun, i.e "surfing".

The vowel sound is definitely an "ö" sound, close to what it is in English.
As for the initial consonant, there is considerable regional variation in how an initial "s" is pronounced. In southern accents (e.g. Austria), this is definitely a voiceless "s" sound, but I (as a speaker of a southern accent) would expect northern speakers to pronounce it in a voiced way (like they pronounce words like Sonne or Sache too).
